# Implementing ls in c, infinite loop

Tags: c

I'm trying to implement `ls` command in c, when I try to recursively list files and folders, I get infinite loop. I need to handle this options `-l, -R, -a, -r and -t`, How can I recursively list files?

```
static int  is_directory(const char *path) 
{
   struct stat statbuf;

   if (stat(path, &statbuf) != 0)
       return 0;
   return S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode);
}

void        read_dir(char *dir_name, char *option)
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;

    dir = opendir(dir_name);
    if (!dir)
    {
        my_putstr("ft_ls: cannot access ");
        perror(dir_name);
        return;
    }
    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        if (is_directory(entry->d_name) && options('R', option))
            read_dir(entry->d_name, option);
        my_putstr(entry->d_name);
        my_putchar('\n');
    }
    closedir(dir);
}

int         main(int ac, char **av)
{
    (void)ac;
    read_dir(av[1], av[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

when I run the program with `./ls . -R` I get infinite loop.

**Allowed functions**

[image: allowed functions]

Comment: 1) No need to recurse when`entry->d_name` is "." or ".."  2) Likely need to change current working directory when recursing.

Comment: Just some simple comments about `main` before venturing further. Better to use the conventional signature `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` and if you had checked `ac` (now `argc`) for enough arguments before using them, you would not have needed to defeat the compiler warning with `(void)ac;`

Comment: @WeatherVane there are restriction on what I can  use and the signature of my `main` should be like that, as required by the school.

Comment: @TenTenPeter the `main` signature is no different, it is only expressed in the typically conventional way. In the real world you **must** check `argc` since what the user passes as arguments (even you in forgetfulness) is outside of your control. If your school says you should ignore `argc` and forbids you checking that, have words with your teacher, go to a better school.

Comment: @WeatherVane I will check `argc` later before I submit my project, here I was just testing my code.

Comment: @TenTenPeter as ever, start as you mean to continue. I didn't get past `main`, sorry. Perhaps you've skimped over other stuff too.

Comment: readdir is not reentrant.  You need to use readdir_r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have decided to use two `while loops`, first listing everything in the current folder, then read again this time checking for folders, and recursively calling `read_dir` function.

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include "libft.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

static int  is_directory(const char *path) 
{
    struct stat statbuf;

   if (stat(path, &statbuf) != 0)
       return 0;
   return S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode);
}

void        read_dir(char *dir_name, char *option)
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;

    dir = opendir(dir_name);
    if (!dir)
    {
        my_putstr("ft_ls: cannot access ");
        perror(dir_name);
        return;
    }
    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        my_putstr(entry->d_name);
        my_putchar('\n');
    }
    closedir(dir);
    dir = opendir(dir_name);
    if (!dir)
    {
        my_putstr("ft_ls: cannot access ");
        perror(dir_name);
        return;
    }
    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL && options('R', option))
    {
        if (is_directory(entry->d_name) && (!(my_strncmp(entry->d_name, ".", 1) == 0)))
            read_dir(entry->d_name, option);
    }
    closedir(dir);
}

int         main(int ac, char **av)
{
    if (ac == 3)
        read_dir(av[1], av[2]);
    else if (ac == 2 || ac > 3)
        //call --help function
    else 
        read_dir(".", "");
return 0;
}
```